# How to send SOAP request with string XML

Tags: c#, api, soap

I need to send request with xml parsed to string. I tried to send this but i got Error Code 400 in response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Send>
      <xml>string</xml>
    </Send>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can I convert xml to string in C# and send this in POSTMAN like this ?

I have tried already with `<![CDATA[ ]]>`

Answer (score 1):

code 400 is bad request, for sending request with xml string in c# use HttpClient.

here an example:

```
string url = "https://your-website.com/soap_service";
string xmlPayload = @"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
  <soap:Header>
    <!-- header elements go here -->
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <!-- body elements go here -->
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpContent content = new StringContent(xmlPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

converting xml to string for using in postman

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root><element>value</element></root>");
string xmlString = doc.OuterXml;
```

1. Open POSTMAN and select the "POST" method in the dropdown.
2. Enter the URL of the endpoint you want to send the request to.
3. In the "Headers" tab, add a header with the key "Content-Type" and the value "text/xml".
4. In the "Body" tab, select "raw" as the body type and "XML (application/xml)" as the data type.
5. Paste the XML string into the body textarea.
6. Click the "Send" button to send the request.